# Android Collage of Images & display the collage in table layout

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, design-patterns, image-processing, android-widget

I am building an android app using <kbd>facebook android sdk</kbd> to get login into facebook.

I am done with login part, now i want to make collage of images. I have displayed all the albums in grid view & when I open any album,it gets open again in grid view with checkbox at top right with each image.

My problem is how to do collage of images, I want Collage of 4 images & 9 images and display them  in `Table Layout`.

Comment: Please update me soon..:-(

Comment: Maybe you could refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913940/multiple-images-in-a-one-single-image if i understand well your question.

Comment: or this https://github.com/jacobmoncur/QuiltViewLibrary

Comment: Thanks Driss. I want to implement the same..

Comment: In my apps i do similar thing https://lh4.ggpht.com/KFbq6W1hJxCaIeBknJSd_X8AADlAXnesRuS2-gJGQVm2YQ8ejEVnbUFdw42EYrl0mA=h900-rw it's a simple algorithm if u need more insight i can write the code for you

Comment: Yes it could be great if you can do it